# Coacervater were more like Viruses or Cells?

Tags: evolution, biochemistry, molecular-evolution

[image]

The answer considers them as first formed living cells as they were precursor of life. But they had no lipid bilayer nor any cellular organization, shouldnt they be more like Viruses ,or like Prions and Viriods ??

Comment: Do not post text as graphics on this list. It discriminates against people with visual disabilities who use screen readers. This is a homework question and should be tagged as such. You need to put more effort in before an amended homework question would be acceptable. For a start, a reference to "coacervates" is necessary. I for one have never heard of them

Comment: @Astrolamb - please do not provide answers-in-disguise as a comment, it deters other users from answering. I have removed your comment.